# select query not working php

Tags: php, ajax

I make an ajax from another page to my php script and it does some computations on the result obtained there and then return those values.

```
<form id="couponForm">
Apply coupon: <input type="text" name="addCode" placeholder="Apply Coupon">
<input class="button"  style="margin-left:10px;" type="submit" value="Apply">
</form>
<script>
     $('#couponForm').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData=$(this).serialize();


    var totalPrice=<?php if(isset($total))echo $total;else echo'"'.'"';?>;

    formData=formData+'&totalPrice='+totalPrice;

    $.ajax({
            url:'/cart/couponAjax.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:formData,
            success: function (content) {
              //something
            }

    });
    })
</script>
```

The above page calls a php script which looks like this

```
     require 'config.php';// contains db credentials
     $totalPrice=$_POST['totalPrice'];
     $couponName=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['addCode']);
     $state=$mysqli->prepare('select * from `coupons` where `name`=?');
     $state->bind_param('s',$couponName);
     $state->execute();
     $result=$state->get_result();

    // $result returns everything as null.
```

When i check the value obtained in the `$result` , it shows me something like this

[image]

DB Looks something like this

[image]
[image]

I am stuck in this thing for hours , what am i doing wrong here ?

Update:

[image]

Comment: you're using a placeholder. do **NOT** escape the value you bind, that just leads to the equivalent of double-escaping. And have you done any basic debugging, like checking return values from the query/prepare calls? Unless you explicitly enable exceptions, mysqli fails by returning boolean false, which you're NOT checking for.

Comment: No `<script>` tags ?

Comment: Some `fetch` should be done next.

Comment: @MarcB yes i did check what it was returning and i did get all the values as empty.Let me update my question.

Comment: @AdrienLeber what?

Comment: you still need to fetch from that result, e.g. `$res = $m->get_result(); while($row = $res->fetch_array()) { ... }`

Comment: @MarcB let me do that

Comment: @MarcB it is working . thanks.

Comment: @u_mulder any one of you can answer the question , could any one of please explain me why did it return null?

Comment: you fetched a result, which is basically just metadata about the result, e.g. field names/types. It's not the actual data (yet).

Comment: @MarcB thanks a ton.